# How to convert a Julian date to a calendar date?

Tags: python, datetime, julian-date

Python version: Python 2.7.15
I have a list of Julian dates in a `numpy` array. The julian dates are defined as days since 1 Jan 4713 BC.

```
dates = [2458050.73958333 2458050.74027778 2458050.74097222 ... 
         2458446.73819445 2458446.73888889 2458446.73958333]
```

I want to convert the dates variable to calendar values like:

```
10/24/2018 04:54:23
```

I've tried using various libraries however, none seem to work. I don't think I need to reinvent the wheel here and create a new function though.

Answer (score 2):

Your best option's probably the [Julian Egg](https://pypi.org/project/julian/), i.e.:

```
import julian

mjd = 54372.78
dt = julian.from_jd(mjd, fmt='mjd')
print(dt)
```

---

**Output:**

```
2007-09-29 18:43:11.999982
```

---

**Installation** (python versions >= 3.2):

```
pip install julian
```

Comment: Thanks Pedro, unfortunately I am using python 2.7 (should have been clear). Also I a caveat to your post I am not using MJD just JD.